# @discordjs/opus Cannot create a Buffer larger than 0x100000000 bytes

Tags: javascript, discord

Я пытаюсь записать и воспроизвести разговор человека в голосовом канале Discord. Бот подключается к каналу по slash-команде и слушает вызвавшего его пользователя. Звук передаётся в кодеке Opus и приходит в виде чанков `stream.on('data', (chunk) => {})`, после чего декодируется и добавляется к предыдущему чанку.

Однако, при попытке кодировать весь звук, переданный за разговор, в строке `connection.playOpusPacket(encoder.encode(phrase))` возникает ошибка

> Cannot create a Buffer larger than 0x100000000 bytes

Код приёма и кодировки:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { OpusEncoder } = require('@discordjs/opus');
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { VoiceConnectionStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, "GUILD_VOICE_STATES"] }); // создаём Discod-клиент

//... добавление slash-команд

// когда использована slash-команда
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

const connection = joinVoiceChannel({ // подключаемся к голосовому каналу
    channelId: interaction.member.voice.channel.id,
    guildId: interaction.member.voice.channel.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: interaction.member.voice.channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});
connection.on(VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, () => {
    const receiver = connection.receiver;
    const stream = receiver.subscribe(interaction.member.id); // подписываемся на прослушку пользователя
    let startSpeak = false;
    let phrase = new Uint8Array();
    const encoder = new OpusEncoder(48000, 1); // создаём Opus encoder/decoder

    stream.on('data', (chunk) => { // когда пользователь говорит
                    if (!startSpeak){
                         console.log("Start speaking");
                         startSpeak = true;
                    }
                    let oldPhrase = phrase;
                    let decoded = encoder.decode(chunk); // декодируем Opus чанк                   
                    phrase = new Uint8Array(oldPhrase.length + decoded.length); // создаём новый массив с длинной старых чанков и нового
                    phrase.set(oldPhrase); // записываем старые чанки
                    phrase.set(decoded, oldPhrase.length); // записываем новый чанк
                });

    connection.receiver.speaking.on('end', () => { // когда пользователь закончил говорить
                    console.log("ended");
                    startSpeak = false;
                    connection.playOpusPacket(encoder.encode(phrase)); // кодируем чанки и проигрываем в Discord
                    phrase = new Uint8Array(); // очищаем массив чанков
                })
});

});
client.login(токен бота);
```

Comment: `0x100000000 bytes` - это 4Гб памяти. 32-разрядные приложения не могут адресовать более 4Гб памяти на процесс.

Comment: Но в коде нет создания Buffer. Как я понял, это происходит в самой библиотеке opus